# Postgres: how can I subtract value at one query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I think I can only get value, subtract value (at Java) and update value. Is it possible to subtract value at cell at one query?

Comment: -1 because "*this question does not show any research effort*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I googled

Comment: The question doesn't show that. If you don't include your attempts this qualifies for "shows no research effort". And: no offense, but this is most basic SQL knowledge that is covered by any decent SQL tutorial. This **is** even part of the Postgres tutorial in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-update.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name where? I can't find example on official site: http://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F9.3%2F&q=subtract

Comment: Did you see my link? Goto the manual, click on "Tutorial", then click on "Updates"

Comment: Yes, sorry - this page just without word 'subtract'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you got the syntax a bit wrong:

```
UPDATE table SET number_of_people = number_of_people - 3 WHERE id = 487364
```

This assumes that number_of_people is an integer value.

Comment: Hmm, I execute: `UPDATE trips SET avaliable_bonus_tickets = avaliable_bonus_tickets - 2 WHERE id = 1935;` I had `avaliable_bonus_tickets` = 2 but after this query my `avaliable_bonus_tickets` = -2

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich No, that can't be. That result could only happen if you did `UPDATE trips SET avaliable_bonus_tickets = - 2` or if the value already was 0. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d93eb/3

Comment: I executed the same query second time and I see correct `0` at database - thank you...